# Enable quick settings in fully managed mode - Android Management API

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I couldn't figure out how to enable quick settings to allow users to connect to a wifi network, among other things, in a fully managed device using Android Management API. I'm using this configuration:

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "autoUpdateMode":"AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY",
      "packageName": "...",
      "installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy":"GRANT"
      
    },
    {
      "packageName":"com.android.settings",
      "installType":"FORCE_INSTALLED"
    }
  ],
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": false,
  "installAppsDisabled":true,
  "modifyAccountsDisabled":true,
  "uninstallAppsDisabled":true,
  "keyguardDisabled":true,
  "bluetoothDisabled":false,
  "credentialsConfigDisabled":true,
  "createWindowsDisabled":true,
  "removeUserDisabled":true,
  "usbFileTransferDisabled":true,
  "autoDateAndTimeZone":"AUTO_DATE_AND_TIME_ZONE_ENFORCED",
  "wifiConfigDisabled":false,
  "kioskCustomLauncherEnabled":true,
  "kioskCustomization":{
    "powerButtonActions": "POWER_BUTTON_AVAILABLE",
    "systemErrorWarnings": "ERROR_AND_WARNINGS_ENABLED",
    "systemNavigation": "NAVIGATION_ENABLED",
    "statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_ENABLED",
    "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED"
  },
  "setWallpaperDisabled":true
}
```

**Current behavior when i swipe from the status bar:**
[image]

**Expected behavior:**
[image]

[Link to Android Management API enterprise policies reference](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies)

Answer (score 0):

The public documentation in this area could be clearer. By default, when a device is in Kiosk, Quick Settings (QS) is never shown.

While [`kioskCustomization.statusBar`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#statusbar) specifies whether system info and notifications are disabled in kiosk mode, it does not allow an admin to toggle QS access. Currently, there is no API to modify QS access on Kiosk devices.

There is an active feature request filed with the AMAPI Engineering team to investigate this as a possible use case for future releases. However, please note there is no guarantee that this feature request will be picked up for work, and there isn't any additional information regarding a timeline for the next steps.

I suggest joining the [Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to keep you posted on the latest updates, information, and releases.